# css replace word in centered sentence and have the width smoothly readjust

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for an effect like the primary one on this page https://sendgrid.com/

The page shows a centered sentence, a word is replaced, the sentence parts left and right to the word, smoothly readjust position according to the new word width.

```html
<body>
    <h1>
        This animation is
        <span id="swappable">awesome</span>
        don't you think?
    </h1>
</body>
```

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#swappable {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```
const swappables = ["bad", "great", "fantastic", "boring"];

let index = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementById("swappable").innerHTML = swappables[index];
    index = index == swappables.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
}, 3000);
```

This code makes the parts snap into place after a word is replaced but

How can I achieve this smooth transition?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I've tried to boil it down thank you

Comment: This is a complex transition. You can't just swap out the text. First you have to collapse the current element and then grow the element back to the new width. You need to work out how you are going to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
const stringsCont = document.querySelector('#strings-cont');
const strings = [...stringsCont.querySelectorAll('.string')];
let active = 0;
next = () =>{
strings.forEach((s,i) => i===active?s.classList.add('active'):s.classList.remove('active'));
  stringsCont.style.width = strings[active].offsetWidth+'px';
  active = (active+1)%strings.length;
}
setInterval(next, 3000);
setTimeout(next,0)
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#strings-cont{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: width .3s ease;
  justify-content: center;
}
.string {
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, top .3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  opacity:0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.string:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left:0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: violet;
}
.string.active {
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
  opacity:1;
  position: static;
  transform: translateX(0);
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.string.active:before {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2.7s ease;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Send Email&nbsp;
<span id="strings-cont" style="width:0">
<span class="string">Lorem Ipsum</span>
<span class="string">Dolor Sit Ammet</span>
<span class="string">Consectetur Adipiscing Elit</span>
<span class="string">Sed Do Eiusmod</span>
</span> 
&nbsp;With Confidence
</h1>
```